# overcoming a break in a span in python

Tags: html, string, python-3.x, list, web-scraping

I use the below code to scrape a website. the 'phone' is a challenge. To make it functional I had to use a find all but would much prefer to use just a find. When I look for it specifically it returns this as a result(I removed the phone number):

(###) ###-####
    
As a result, I can only get  and it returns nothing else, no phone number at all. The find_all at least returns the phone number but then I spend a lot of time cleaning it up further from the list (the number does not consistently land in the -1 index) HELP!

```
def BSassign(letters):
    BNameDict = {}
    for i in range(len(letters)):
        if letters[i].find(attrs = {'class': 'biz-name js-analytics-click'}) == None:
            break
        else:
           BNameDict[i] = {'name': letters[i].find(attrs={'class': 'biz-name js-analytics-click'}).text,
                           'phone': letters[i].find_all('span'),
                           'address': letters[i].find(attrs={'class': 'service-area'})}
    return BNameDict
```

Comment: <___span class="biz-phone">
        (###) ###-####
    </span___>

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of working... it still has the end span html coding at the end... but it is worlds better already. And yes, I did attempt the slice using 13, 14 and 15 character index lengths and it just returned a blank.

```
def BSassign(letters):
    BNameDict = {}
    for i in range(len(letters)):
        if letters[i].find(attrs = {'class': 'biz-name js-analytics-click'}) == None:
            break
        else:
            Phones = str(letters[i].find_all('span'))
            thisisirritating = Phones.find('(')
            Phones = Phones[thisisirritating:]
            BNameDict[i] = {'name': letters[i].find(attrs={'class': 'biz-name js-analytics-click'}).text,
                            'phone': Phones,
                            'address': letters[i].find(attrs={'class': 'service-area'})}
    return BNameDict
```